# Can't add physical disk to existing storage pool in S2D

Tags: storage-spaces

Get-StoragePool -IsPrimordial $False | Add-PhysicalDisk -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True)

[Failure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGZwb.png)

[Available Disk CanPool is True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJgHs.png)

Can help me please

[Show physical disk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMzcU.png)

[disk only available for add new storage pool image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JRvF.png)

[Disk don't show in add disk to existing storage pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUXL0.png)

Comment: You could embed the failure image in the question. Provide more context about your question and list the steps you have already tried to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my error by move storage pool to node have new disks.